# What is this in react import { HomePage } from '@/HomePage'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I know its importing a file but I don't know what the "@" stands for, I have seen a bunch of code snippets using this same syntax.

I tried implementing the same scenario in any way I thought could be possible but still no success

Answer (score 0):

They are webpack alias import, this configuration help to shorten your absolute/relative path.

Read more here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Answer (score 0):

This is used when you want to use Scope Packages.

What are Scope Packages?
Ans - Scopes are a way of grouping related packages together, and also affect a few things about the way npm treats the package.

[Please check this docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scope)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `babel-plugin-root-import` in your `devDependencies` in `package.json` (If using `yarn: yarn add babel-plugin-root-import --dev`). Then in your .`babelrc` add the following lines into `plugins` key:

```
"plugins": [
[
  "babel-plugin-root-import",
  {
    "rootPathPrefix": "@"
  }
]
]
```

Now, you can use `@.` For example:

**Instead of:**

```
import xx from '../../utils/somefile'
```

**You Can:**

```
import xx from '@/utils/somefile'
```